# Наиболее близкая дата к заданной

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt, datetime

Есть строка `QString` с начальной датой `2014.08.16 10:14:33`, далее есть  список из трёх дат (их может быть больше), к примеру:

1. `2014.08.17 17:28:53`
2. `2014.08.16 10:27:37`
3. `2014.08.15 12:33:17`

Как найти самую близкую дату из этого списка к дате начальной? Т.е. в итоге должно получиться: самой близкой датой к изначальной являться строка `2014.08.16 10:27:37`. Как понимаю нужно как то перевести строки в `QDateTime` и дальше их сравнивать с начальной датой, что ближе к начальной, ту и выводим. Как будет выглядеть данный алгоритм ?

Comment: @andreycha языки всё-таки разные.

Comment: @alexolut а алгоритм один -- про него и спрашивают.

Comment: @andreycha тогда языковые теги вообще надо убрать.

Answer (score 5):

1. Для преобразования строки в дату можно использовать [`QDateTime::fromString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-1) с форматом `"yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"`.
2. Когда все строки преобразованы, отдаленность одной даты от другой можно проверить через [`QDateTime::secsTo`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#secsTo), обернутую в `std::abs`.
3. Вывести ту, которая даст меньшее число.